# How to enable auto launch apps option programatically

Tags: android

How to enable auto launch apps option in android programatically in all the devices nougat version to My android application(Oppo, Vivo, One plus....).

Comment: Please explain.

Comment: are you  want to open the app when device is switched on
?

Comment: Please refer this link: https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/apps-auto-launch-in-android-n.484674/

Comment: No, I need to enable auto launch apps option from setting programatically like locations enable